# Flattening a Periodic Snapshot Fact Table

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, data-warehouse

I've got an unusual reporting requirement from a customer, which is really giving me fits. My source is a data warehouse periodic snapshot fact table which is at the grain of 1 record per customer per company period. What they require is essentially a modified pivot.

Please consider the simplified example. I've used Customer Name in this example to make the records easier to follow, the real solution using the Fact table and Dimensions with surrogate keys.

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#PeriodicSnapshot') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE #PeriodicSnapshot

CREATE TABLE #PeriodicSnapshot
(
   CompanyPeriod        INT
  ,CustomerName         VARCHAR (25)
  ,AdvancedThisPeriod   DECIMAL (9, 2)
  ,PaymentsThisPeriod   DECIMAL (9, 2)
)

Insert into #PeriodicSnapshot 
(CompanyPeriod, CustomerName, AdvancedThisPeriod, PaymentsThisPeriod)
Values
 (201401, 'Yoda', 200.00, 50.00)
,(201401, 'Darth Vader', 0, 0)
,(201402, 'Yoda', 0, 0)
,(201402, 'Darth Vader', 100.00, 20.00 )
,(201403, 'Yoda', 0, 50.00)
,(201403, 'Darth Vader', 0, 0)
```

I need to take the table above and provide the results like this, preferably using T-SQL.

[image: Flattened Data Set]

Please note that the column names are aliased because the grain is changed to one Customer per Year. Keep in mind that there are actually more than 30 columns in the original table and they'll have to be flattened as well.

I realize that this is terrible, and they're abusing the database this way. However, the customer insists that they need the data in this format to feed a separate prediction algorithm. My only other option is to actually instantiate these tables, one for each year since 2008 and going forward.

The query to generate this data set does not need to perform particularly well because it will only be run once a week (for the current year) and over a weekend.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

i havent figured out how to pivot in sql, but the code below works

```
with companyper as (
select 
CustomerName, 

case when CompanyPeriod = '201401' then (AdvancedThisPeriod) end as 'AdvacnedThisPeroid_201401', 
case when CompanyPeriod = '201401' then (PaymentsThisPeriod) end as 'PaymentsThisPeriod_201401', 
case when CompanyPeriod = '201402' then (AdvancedThisPeriod) end as 'AdvacnedThisPeroid_201402', 
case when CompanyPeriod = '201402' then (PaymentsThisPeriod) end as 'PaymentsThisPeriod_201402'

from #PeriodicSnapshot )

select
CustomerName, 
SUM(AdvacnedThisPeroid_201401) as ATP201401, 
SUM(PaymentsThisPeriod_201401) AS PTP201401, 
SUM(AdvacnedThisPeroid_201402) as ATP201402, 
SUM(PaymentsThisPeriod_201402) AS PTP201402


from
companyper

group by CustomerName
```

[image]

Comment: Or you can put the query into excel and have excel pivot the data out, right click, refresh as needed.

Comment: Or you can run a rather trivial MDX query.